# OpenGL Vertex Buffer Object does not work

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer

I have a bunny.h which contains the following data:

```
bunny[] | vertex coordinates xyz

NUM_TRIANGLES | the amount of triangles for the bunny

normals[] | the normals for each triangle

triangles[] | indices for the triangles
```

I want to use the data for a vertex buffer object.

here is how I try to load the data

```
GLfloat values[NUM_TRIANGLES*3];
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TRIANGLES*3; i++)
        values[i] = bunny[i];

  //  init and bind a VBO (vertex buffer object) //
    glGenBuffers(1, &bunnyVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bunnyVBO);


  //  copy data into the VBO //
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(values), &values, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  // init and bind a IBO (index buffer object) //
    glGenBuffers(1, &bunnyIBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bunnyIBO);

  //  copy data into the IBO //
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangles), &triangles, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  // unbind active buffers //
  glBindVertexArray(0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Later in the program I want to render the buffers using this code:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bunnyVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bunnyIBO);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_TRIANGLES, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, triangles);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

OpenGL is working fine, but I dont see the bunny... (the data is not corrupted or anything like that, the error is in my code)
Can some please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any call to `glVertexPointer`.  And if you want to use the elements from the VBO, it should be

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_TRIANGLES, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Comment: Where do I have to call glVertexPointer - Loading data or rendering data?

Comment: @glethien:  During rendering.  The pointer you pass to it is an offset within the vertex VBO, in this case zero.

Comment: I tried, but still black - Rendering inlcudes glVertexPointer before glDrawElements.

Comment: There are many possible reasons to get nothing but black in OpenGL, e.g., the geometry may be black, or you modelview or projection matrices may be wrong.  There's not enough information to tell what's wrong.